# Using multiple gsubs in one r function

Tags: r

So keep in mind I started using R for two days now, and for our first assignment we have to create a function, and I'm planning on just doing basic encryption kind of thing.

This is what I have so far:

```
g <- c("Hello, this is a test, do you understand?")

convert <- function(a) {
    gsub("H","$",a)
    gsub("e","f",a)
    gsub("l","*",a)
    gsub("o","7",a)
}

convert(g)
```

See the problem is this outputs:

```
"Hell7, this is a test, d7 y7u undertstand?"
```

How would I get the multiple `gsub`s to work?

Comment: You have to assign the outcome of each gsub call to something (like a)

Comment: `g<- gsub("H","$",a)` ...etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `chartr` for this if it's a character-by-character type replacement:

```
g <- c("Hello, this is a test, do you understand?")
chartr("Helo", "$f*7", g)
# [1] "$f**7, this is a tfst, d7 y7u undfrstand?"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(c('H', 'e', 'l', 'o'), c('$', 'f', '*', '7'), g)
#[1] "$f**7, this is a tfst, d7 y7u undfrstand?"
```

---

Or `gsubfn` from `gsubfn` package

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('.', list(H='$', e='f', l='*', o='7'), g)
#[1] "$f**7, this is a tfst, d7 y7u undfrstand?"
```