# Replace subscript number in string

Tags: r, regex, gsub, subscript

I have the following vector and I want to have the subscript numbers (e.g. ₆, ₂) to be replaced with 'normal' numbers.

```
vec = c("C₆H₄ClNO₂", "C₆H₆N₂O₂", "C₆H₅NO₃", "C₉H₁₀O₂", "C₈H₈O₃")
```

I could lookup all subscript values and replace them individually:

```
gsub('₆', '6', vec)
```

But isn't there a pattern in regex for it?

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976910/regex-to-replace-all-superscript-numbers) for javascript but I couldn't translate it into R.

Comment: `chartr("₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉", "0123456789", vec)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple strings in one gsub() or chartr() statement in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949945/replace-multiple-strings-in-one-gsub-or-chartr-statement-in-r)

Comment: I don't know anything about R, could you do something like in C, where you "add" the difference in the ascii table to a letter ? i.e, assume the subscript are next to each other in the ascii table, substract `1` and `₁` to know the delta, and apply it to each number. Otherwise I'd just make a map (₁ -> 1, etc)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's not really a duplicate imho, since I'm asking for a pattern in regex for sub/superscripts. But yes, this would be one possibility.

Comment: You need no regex here. `chartr` is from base R, use it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple gsubs in one r function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318530/using-multiple-gsubs-in-one-r-function)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6954017/680068

Comment: This question is in my opinion significantly different from the proposed duplicate, which is why I voted to undelete and reopen. Besides, `chartr` is way too underappreciated and deserves more of our love.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`chartr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/chartr):

> Translate characters in character vectors

Solution:

```
chartr("₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉", "0123456789", vec)
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/YY8UON)

**BONUS**

To normalize superscript digits use

```
chartr("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹", "0123456789", "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹")
## => [1] "0123456789"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` to extract all the subscript numbers, convert it to equivalent integer subtract `8272` (because that is the difference between integer value of `₆` and `6` and all other equivalents) and convert it back.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(vec, "\\p{No}", function(m) intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(m) - 8272))
#[1] "C6H4ClNO2" "C6H6N2O2"  "C6H5NO3"   "C9H10O2"   "C8H8O3"
```

---

As pointed out by @Wiktor Stribiżew `"\\p{No}"` matches more than subscript digits to only match subscripts from 0-9 we can use (thanks to @thothal )

```
str_replace_all(vec, "[\U2080-\U2089]", function(m) intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(m) - 8272))
```

Comment: `\p{No}` [matches more than subscript digits](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%5Cp%7BNo%7D%5D&g=&i=) and it is not the solution OP needs.

Comment: You should replace your regex to `[\U2080-\U2089]`