# How to remove Subscripts from the column names of the data table in R?

Tags: r, datatable

I have some columns in a data frame with column names of CO₂.I want to change this to CO2 (no subscripts). How can I do this? in the data table, it reads as `CO2` and when I print column names, it reads as CO₂.

I tried following code but it refuses to change.

[image]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(dataset)`?

Comment: looks like duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007087/replace-subscript-number-in-string

Comment: @Quinten I'd strongly advise asking for `dput` of data **subsets**, not whole data. Especially on a question like this that is about the column names, we don't need or want the whole data set. `dput(dataset[1:5, ])` is good--or in this case `dataset` appears to be a `list` so `dput(dataset[[1]][1:5, ])`.

Comment: @GregorThomas, You are completely right, my bad.